# Can't find id_rsa in .ssh folder

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I want to connect my SQL developer with oracle vision demo database. According to the article I read I have to run `ssh opc@158.101.151.204 -i .ssh/id_rsa -L  1521:localhost:1521` but it gave me error. `id_rsa` file is not in a directory.

So I check in folder `.ssh`, there're only 2 files: `authorized_key` and `knowhosts`.

Anyone please advise what should I do?

Comment: `.ssh/id_rsa` is referencing to private key. You will need to generate  pair of keys. Public and private. The private will be in .ssh/id_rsa of your computer and the public key must be present in the authorized_key file of the server you are trying to connect. If you are using Windows you can use the Putty software suite for managing the sessions and tunnels. Find here how to generate the keys by command line: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4078/6jd6cjru7/index.html

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).